# python num_worker in data loader not working

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation, dataloader

I am trying to run the code from this [repo](https://github.com/visinf/1-stage-wseg)

but it never loads the images when num_worker is > 0.

However, when I set num_worker = 0, it loads the data, but then all my losses are NaN.

I am not sure why num_worker is not loading the data

Is there an issue with the version of things or something else?

And what exactly is num_worder supposed to do and why does it only load data when its in the main process, i.e set to 0?

For more information, I started the issue [here](https://github.com/visinf/1-stage-wseg/issues/24), but then the author seems to have suddenly disappeared

I have a 3090 with 5950x cpu and 128 gb ram, so hardware or space is not an issue